# Implement updating location to server in the background mode- iOS

Tags: ios

What I want do is:

Updating the current location of iOS device to my server periodically(every 10min), even my App is in the background mode.

What I have done:

1. Add the `Required Background Modes` in the plist; and asked requestAlwaysAuthorization.
2. Set background refreshing of this App in Setting.
3. Set a NSTimer to get the location(using `CLLocationManager`) periodically.
4. When the `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:`delegate called, updating location use HTTPGET to the server.
   My problem:
   When App is in foreground it works fine, but the update location method does not run in background, server cannot receive my location data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have enable Location in background modes from project settings -> Target -> Capabilities.

[image]

Instead of location send to server in every 10 mins , I would like to suggest you use startMonitoringVisits() and locationManager(_:didVisit:) delegate to get user location. Because your approach will be too much battery killer.

Comment: Thanks Stantu, I will try that, haven't try startMonitoringVisits() before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your background task with below code and then your task is finish you have to end background task

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

}

for more info: [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)